# Primary Key of Associative Entity

Tags: database, entity-framework, erd

In this ERD:

[image]

Certificate Entity is an Associative Entity and it has a unique identifier - Certificate Number. Since an Associative Entity inherits its primary key from other entities. The key field of associated entity are primary key of each end entity is a foreign key on the associated entity, and both foreign keys combined together become a primary key(Concepts from Textbook).

Is the primary key of the Certificate Entity should be a composite key which contains three parts: CertificateNumber, EmployeeID, CourseID ?

Or its primary key is CertificateNumber, and takes EmployeeID, CourseID as attributes of this entity??

I'm confused on this question because normally an associated entity doesn't have its own identifier(Certificate Number). It just take primary keys from other entities combined as composite key(EmployeeID, CourseID), then use that composite key as its identifier.

Thank you

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associative entities don't have a primary key based on their own attributes.  In your first diagram, you created an associative entity with the functional dependency `(Employee_ID, Course_ID) -> Date_Completed`.  Note that while `Employee_ID` and `Course_ID` are columns in the table, they're not attributes.  An attribute in the ER model is a mapping from an entity set to a value set.  Foreign keys are components of a relationship and don't map to a value set.

In your second diagram, by adding a surrogate key, your associative entity becomes a regular entity which is in relationships with `Employee` and `Course`.  Your primary key is just `Certificate_Number`, but a unique constraint on `(Employee_ID, Course_ID)` is probably a good idea.  The relationships are represented by the functional dependencies `Certificate_Number -> Employee_ID` and `Certificate_Number -> Course_ID` recorded in the `Certificate` table.

You could also keep it an associative entity and use `(Employee_ID, Course_ID)` as the primary key and make `Certificate_Number` a regular attribute, though uniquely constrained (and probably auto-incremented).  In this case, the diagram would look like your first one but with an extra attribute on the relationship.